# Where do I submit a change proposal for a close vote comment?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

case:

The text for *NoRepro*

> This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

lacks one comma, it **should** read

> This describes a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own...

(mark the comma after reproduced)

Comment: Here on meta, as mods can edit it after community has expressed approval or suggested modifications. Usually tagged feature-request

Comment: I've fixed this. We just need to wait for one of the other mods to approve my change and it will go live.

Comment: I'm usually good at spotting this issues but I must confess this one escaped me. Good catch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We just did this. The close reason now reads:

> This describes a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.